# How to fit range of calculate calomn to pivot table size in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table that changes row number after each refresh. Near to it (next column), I created a calculate column that is not part of the pivot table, but that uses pivot table data.

I have been dragging down the last cell from my calculate column in order for it to fit the changing pivot table size to calculate all the values.

Is there a way to fit the calculate column to Pivot table size automatically?

If there is a way and it depends on VBA code, is there an option to insert it like a formula and not run it as Macro?
Thanks.

Comment: Just populate more rows with your formula. For example you expect it to be 10,000 data then put your formula in `10,000` rows. Display `""` or blank if there's no `Pivot Data` yet.

Comment: I think it is good solution for me, but I not familiar with this formula, what I did till now is very simple I divide column C and column D and that all. How should I edit it for 100 cells and not display results for "N/A" cells?

Comment: It not good for me because if I do this I'm getting several rows for each result that I get. I want to calculate all data first and only then add the final divider (the best option that I found till now is to add it near the pivot table and use pivot data).

Answer (score 0):

Add this routine to the worksheet code with `Option Explicit` enabled at the top.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Dim CalcCol As String, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
   CalcCol = "A" 'Write the column name here
   FirstRow = Me.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Cells(1,1).Row
   LastRow = Me.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Cells(Me.PivotTables(1).TableRange2.Rows.count,1).Row

   Me.Range(CalcCol & FirstRow).Formula = 'your formula as a string here
   Me.Range(CalcCol & FirstRow & ":" & CalcCol & LastRow).FillDown
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe im doing something wrong but nothing is change There is a way to do it by simple formula like L42 user suggested?